# Way to figure out the flow of javascript function with the help of firebug or IE 8 debugger or chrome debugger?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, firebug

I have below html code in one of the opensource project.

```
 <form action="/wiki/bin/view/Main/Search">
 <div class="globalsearch">
 <label class="hidden" for="headerglobalsearchinput">Search</label>
 <input id="headerglobalsearchinput" class="globalsearchinput withTip" type="text"      size="15"      value="search..." name="text" autocomplete="off">
 <input class="button" type="image" src="/wiki/resources/icons/xwiki/search.png" alt="Go"      value="Go">
 </div>
 </form>
```

on click of serach.png icon, call goes to server side. Actually i want to do some stuff in javascript function on click of search icon. But i am not able to figure out whichh javascript
gets called on click of  search icon. **Is there any way i can figure the flow of javascript function with the help of  firebug or IE 8 debugger or chrome debugger ? As the type is image there should be some javascript function which must be submitting the form.**

Comment: An input element with a type of image will submit the form when it's clicked. No javascript required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using google chrome and push ctrl+shift+i and click scripts and then push the pause button on the right hand side. That will then pause the scripts when they next run. you can step through and such when it's paused and debug that way?

Comment: You may need to add onlick="return false;" to you input as well as that will post the form regardless of javascript

Comment: i think what you are trying to say here is . imediately after clicking some button etc. just push pause button. It will stop the script exceution right at the moment when we click paue button. Right? In that case we have to be raelly quick in pressing the pause button (right after clicking some event on UI page). Right?

Comment: You should be able to push pause before clicking anything as well. If you're not getting a breakpoint appear before it redirects that's due to your form posting. did you add the onclick="return false" to the input as well?